# Using excel type viewer on database tables with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I know in Silverlight 4 excel spread sheets can be read but I need to somehow have Excel type functionality (with filters etc) built into my silverlight application but using the data from my database.

Is this possible and/or are the any 3rd party components to do this?

JD.

Comment: Excel spreadsheets can be read in Silverlight? How?

Comment: Otaku - you can access COM objects in Silverlight 4 out of browser applications - here's a breif example: http://team.interknowlogy.com/blogs/danhanan/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-take-advantage-of-full-trust.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar using just the Silverlight DataGrid from the toolkit. If you want more sophisticated functionality you would need to look at commercial data grids like those from Telerik.